# Non-trivial upper bound on singular value of diagonal-constant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

$A$ is a  $m \times m$ diagonal-constant matrix with $1$ on the main diagonal and $2$ on the first superdiagonal. all other elements are equal to $0$.

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2& 0& 0& 0&0& ...&0 \\ 0& 1& 2& 0& 0& 0& ...& 0\\0&0&1&2&...\\...&&&&&&&2\\0&0&0&...&&&&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

And we know:

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1& -2& 4& &&&&-2^{m-1} \\0& 1& -2& 4& &&&-2^{m-2}\\ &&\\&&&\\\\0&0&0&&&1&-2&4\\0&0&0&&&&1&-2\\0&0&0&...&&&&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand the eigenvalues for matrix $A$ is $1$. It seems we can give a nontrivial upper bound on $\sigma_{m}$, $m^{th}$ singular value, knowing $A^{-1}$. Does any one know how?

Thanks.

Comment: You are incorrect about that singular value.  $1$ is an *eigenvalue*, but not a singular value.  In the $2 \times 2$ case, we compute
$$
\sigma_1 = \sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt{2}} \approx 2.4
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right. I was totally confused. I will work on it again.Thanks.

Comment: Omnomnomnom I don not have a clue how you came up with bound. I don't know any relation between $A^{-1}$ and Singular values.

Comment: There is no obvious relation.  And I didn't come up with a *bound*, I directly computed the singular value for a specific example.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. I thought there should be a general answer for the upper bound.

Comment: None that I know of uses the ideas you're trying to apply here.  Of course, it's possible to get *an* upper bound, but I'm not sure how strong you need the upper bound to be.  An easy way to get an upper bound is to compute the Frobenius norm, but that uses nothing about the inverse.

Comment: It seems there should be  a relation between the question and  $A^{-1}$. You meant there is a theorem that implies we can use Frobenius norm as an upper bound for singular value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your first sentence. Does this question come from a certain source?  What make's you think that we should consider $A^{-1}$?  And yes, I am saying that there is such a theorem.

Comment: Yes, It is a question from the book, which is asking to give a nontrivial upperbound on $\sigma_{m}$. It suggested to write a MATLAB code but should  justify it analytically.

Comment: Okay... does $m$ refer to a specific value with respect to the matrix (is it the last singular value)?  Or is $\sigma_m$ just any singular value?

Comment: $A$ is $m \times m$. m is the dimension of matrix.

Comment: Well, now this makes much more sense.  In fact, we have $\sigma_m(A) = 1/\sigma_1(A^{-1})$.  Perhaps that is of use to you.

Comment: Interesting, Sorry for too many questions. where is this coming from ?

Comment: One way is to use the definitions
$$
\sigma_1(A) = \max \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}, \qquad 
\sigma_m(A) = \min \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$
and make the substitution $x = A^{-1}y$.

Comment: Although the mystery of $m$ is solved, still one prevails: what is  $\sigma_m$?

Comment: Correction: $A$ is a $m \times m$ matrix. $\sigma_{m}$ is the $m^{th}$ singular value of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for your guidance. I just now understand it is trivial.

Comment: Could someone expand on how $\frac{1}{\sigma}A^{-1}$ gives an answer in the reals? Wouldn't that result in a matrix?

Comment: @Math4Life If it helps I think I had a typo. $\sigma_m(A) = \frac{1}{\sigma_1(A^{-1})}$

Comment: Thank you. I was misreading the notation as well. I thought that $\sigma_1(A^{-1})$ was multiplication at first then I figured it out. :)